# Watir-webdriver slowly firefox

Tags: firefox, watir-webdriver

i have problem with watir-webdriver and Firefox 3.6, the cucumber is finished

```
1 scenario (1 passed)
4 steps (4 passed)
0m7.983s
rake aborted!
Timeout::Error
```

and after 3 minutes load the page when the cucumber say me Timeout::Error

the watir-webdriver version (0.6.4, 0.6.3)
the selenium-webdriver version (2.32.1)

the code is

```
require "rubygems"
require 'watir-webdriver'
require 'selenium-webdriver'

$browser1 = Watir::Browser.new :firefox

$browser1.goto "url"
```

where are the problem ?

thanks !

Comment: You are aware of the fact that you are asking us to read your mind? How could we possibly help you when you did not provide the code that causes the error?

Comment: Are you sure that Firefox 3.6 is supported by selenium-webdriver? I could not find a list of supported versions, but I would guess they only maintain the latest releases.

Comment: Hi Zeliko, can you help me, please ?

Comment: i quit the selenium-webdriver and have some problem

Comment: could be because using [link] (http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml)

Comment: could it be because your firefox is ANCIENT...

Answer (score 0):

Firefox 3.6 is obsolete.   The [latest stats](http://www.netmarketshare.com/browser-market-share.aspx?qprid=2&qpcustomd=0) place the market share of users still on this version at 0.58%

Is it worth your time to test against a browser platform that is used by such a small number of people?

The current version of opera has nearly three times the userbase..  The current version of Safari over five times the users..

Update to a modern version of firefox and test against what most firefox users will be running